# Javascript works only after reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, loading

I am developing a website with a [Wondergrid](http://www.is-real.net/experiments/css3/wonder-webkit/) animated elements (JS). The problem is every time the page is loaded on the fresh system (no cache), the script won't work. After reloading/refreshing the page it works fine:
http://kate.projectsbin.com/1/

Any clues to improve it, please? (I am designer, not a programmer)

Comment: There might be some javascript which is failing. Try to see the error in the error console and solve the error. It might solve the issue. Try importing the javascript at the top.

Comment: The blue boxes should change there shapes on mouse position on-screen. On fresh load they don't - you have to reload (webkit browsers + FF). No errors in the console.

Comment: Have you included `js` in `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: Yes, in wonderkit.js (the end of the file).

Comment: To see if it is an issue with the images not being fully loaded when you initialize wonderkit, change the `$(document).ready()` handler to a `$(window).load()` handler. Also, there is a script at the bottom binding jQuery events. You should probably wrap that in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thank you, Dom, I implemented your ideas here: http://kate.projectsbin.com/3/ No go though :(

Answer (score 1):

It's easier as an answer, so, regarding comments above ...

A document ready function goes like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    ... stuff ...
});
```

and a window load function goes like

```
$(window).load( function() {
    ... stuff ...
});
```